# Not able to change text color on all panels in leaflet

Tags: color, leaflet

When I try to change the color of all text in `leaflet` class. Only the first four panels get affected. The last two panels remain black in color. How can this be changed?

MWE

```
\documentclass[notumble]{leaflet}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\color{red}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but since this shows up on Google I think it might still be good to answer:

The workaround I found is to do this when using the `subfiles` package to split the panes:

```
% !TeX root = ../flyer.tex
\documentclass[../flyer.tex]{subfiles}
\graphicspath{{\subfix{../images/}}}
\svgpath{{\subfix{../images/}}}

\begin{document}
\globalcolor{white}
\section*{Where can I learn more?}
\end{document}
```

Sadly, I don't think this works nicely in other scenarios. But hopefully it helps. Just `\AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{white}}` alone seems to not work for pages 5 and 6.